# A nonmetrizable image of a metrizable space

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

It is well known that a hausdorff continuous image of a compact metric space is metrizable. What is  a  counterexample for noncompact case?

Comment: Pick any non-metrizable space $X$ and consider a discrete metric space $Y$ with sufficiently many points such that there is a surjective function $Y\to X$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez thank you. Please see my comment to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be an infinite set, let $\mathcal{T}_\text{d}$ be the discrete topology on $X$, and $\mathcal{T}$ any non-metrizable Hausdorff topology on $X$. Then the identity mapping $\operatorname{id}_X : X \to X$ is a continuous function from $( X , \mathcal{T}_{\text{d}} )$ onto $( X , \mathcal{T} )$, and the discrete topology is metrizable (by the discrete metric).

Comment: thank you. Is there a counter example when both space are locally compact and the map is proper?(motivated by Gelfand Duality)

Comment: @Maiano  and Uunfra_chicda-ura-wukru   In the other word, is it true to say that a commutative nonunital C* algebra $C_{0}(X)$ is separable iff $X$ is metrizable

Comment: Unfortunately, I have little feel for proper mappings, and cannot really answer your first question. As for the second question, I think that if $X$ is an uncountable discrete space, then $C_0(X)$ is not separable.

Comment: @unfru-chikda-ura-wukru  thank you for your comment on $C_{0}(X)$ when $X$ is uncountable.